# Why does the capacity of a slice change when you drop the first n items but not the last n items?

Tags: go

I am going through the tour of Go and wanted to know the following:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    printSlice(s)

    // Drop its last two values
    s = s[:len(s)-2]
    printSlice(s)

    // Drop its first two values.
    s = s[2:]
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

Result:

```
len=6 cap=6 [2 3 5 7 11 13]
len=4 cap=6 [2 3 5 7]
len=2 cap=4 [5 7]
```

Why does the capacity of the slice stay the same when you drop the last 2 items but changes when you drop the first 2?

https://play.golang.org/p/ZNKwOYKDqOi

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: I'm also confused by this still. It's been a few years since this question was asked and since then, the tour has added the following piece: "You can extend a slice's length by re-slicing it, provided it has sufficient capacity." and the code example: 
// Drop its first two values.
 s = s[2:]
 printSlice(s)
 
 s = s[:4]
 printSlice(s)
I don't understand why it makes any sense that they can drop the first 2 elements, which loses the reference to the first 2 and recalculates capacity, and allows you to reslice back to the end of the original slice, but you cannot retrieve the omitted 2...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go slices are implemented as a struct:

`src/runtime/slice.go`:

```
type slice struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
    cap   int
}
```

---

Revise your `printSlice` function to show the pointer to the underlying array:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    printSlice(s)

    // Drop its last two values
    s = s[:len(s)-2]
    printSlice(s)

    // Drop its first two values.
    s = s[2:]
    printSlice(s)
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    var ptr *int
    if cap(s) >= 1 {
        ptr = &s[:cap(s)][0]
    }
    fmt.Printf("ptr=%p len=%d cap=%d %v\n", ptr, len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/pk3cpE_LsUV

Output:

```
ptr=0x450000 len=6 cap=6 [2 3 5 7 11 13]
ptr=0x450000 len=4 cap=6 [2 3 5 7]
ptr=0x450008 len=2 cap=4 [5 7]
```

See how your slicing operations adjust the pointer, the length, and the capacity. A slice is simply a view of or window into the underlying array.

---

References:

[The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[The Go Programming Language Specification:](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

- [Slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)
- [Slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)

Answer (score 1):

A slice has a buffer under the covers. The capacity is the size of that buffer. Removing items from the end does not alter the buffer size.

You are creating a new slice from an existing slice but starting the index of the new slice at 2. The new slice still points to the same underlying buffer (but offset by 2). The buffer size (and capacity) for this new slice is thus 2 less.

Capacity makes sense when you see how append works. Append tries to reuse the same underlying buffer - but if the capacity is filled, then a reallocation and copy is performed.